# Update excel values depend on another values PHPOfficeSpreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

I would like to update the cell value from excel file dynamically using phpofficespreadsheet library. The scenario is, get the mysql query as follow:

```
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $datas = array(
        'id' => $row['IdNumber']
        'address' => $row['address']
    );
```

And in my excel file at colum A contains idNumber, and at column B contains address.

What I tried so far is:

```
$inputFileName = 'datas.xlsx';
    $inputFileType = ucfirst(substr($inputFileName, strrpos($inputFileName, '.') + 1));
    $reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    
    $spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);
 
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $last_row = (int) $sheet->getHighestRow();
    
//Update B column depends on A column as ID Number values

if($sheet->getCell('A')->getValue() == $datas['idNumber']){
    $sheet->setCellValue('B', $datas['address']);
}
```

that's script return the wrong coordinates, Tried all the results i got from searchnig over the net, but not working. Anyone know how to achieved this?